Solana transaction confirmation error after successful transaction
   async function makePayment() {
        try {
            setProcessing(true);
            
            let success = false;
            while (!success) {
                const transaction = new Transaction().add(
                    SystemProgram.transfer({
                        fromPubkey: publicKey!,
                        toPubkey: new PublicKey("BEwvWR2TjmkgPJ8kCBFkqHNRGDuVWH4AyvnFCiFaEcAs"),
                        lamports: 22348000, // 0.022348 sol // 3.10 usd  // 260 inr
                    })
                );
    
                const { context: { slot: minContextSlot }, value: { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } } = await connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext();
    
                const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection, { minContextSlot });
                
                try {
                    await connection.confirmTransaction({ signature, blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight });
                    success = true;
                    console.log("Payment succeeded with signature:", signature);
                    setTxSignature(signature);
                    alert("Payment success. Now add task!");
                } catch (confirmationError) {
                    console.warn("Confirmation failed, retrying with a new blockhash...", confirmationError);
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            setProcessing(false);
            console.error("Payment failed:", err);
            alert("Payment failed. Please try again.");
        } finally {
            setProcessing(false);
        }
    }

After initiating the transaction of the mentioned lamports, it is getting success but confirmation is giving following error:
upload.tsx:63 Confirmation failed, retrying with a new blockhash... TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature 64UmRfE4D5y1T9gGi2aV4m2Y13gqn3WgUHhfRmRrcyCT4b7xYfnanvZrnDntjuz4eqjQMEchQHcwFnWfNnCP3Gf2 has expired: block height exceeded.
at Connection.confirmTransactionUsingBlockHeightExceedanceStrategy (connection.ts:4059:15)
at async Connection.confirmTransaction (connection.ts:3870:14)
at async makePayment (upload.tsx:57:21)
I tried changing the factor of verifying transaction to only signature and it is showing the strategy is deprecated
